# How are we accessing local variables?

Tags: javascript

There is a test to whether `a` will be undefined or `b` will be undefined. However what is confusing me is, how are we accessing both a and b inside the console.log, when both are local variables. Does it have to do with the way we defined a function inside a parentheses ? I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to understand how it works.

```
(function(){
    var a = b = 3;
})();

console.log("a defined? " + (typeof a !== 'undefined'));
console.log("b defined? " + (typeof b !== 'undefined'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From outside the function, your `console.log()` calls can access `b` but not `a`. The variable `a` is declared in the function by the `var` statement; the variable `b` however is made implicitly global by the initialization expression for `a`.

The `var` statement is interpreted as if it were written

```
var a = (b = 3);
```

The syntax of a `var` statement is such that the initialization does *not* define `b` as a local variable. You can verify that with code like yours, or by adding

```
"use strict";
```

right before the `var` statement and noting that you'll get an error from the implicit global use of `b`.

Comment: I tried to the same thing in a first class normal function and both came up undefined. why does it work differently in an IIFE ? is there any readings on IIFE you could send me to understand how it works differently than a normal function ?

Comment: @Mozein It doesn't work differently in an IIFE. Did you *call* your "normal" function? The IIFE involves the creation of a function and a call to the function. If you just write a regular function without calling it, then the code in the function won't do anything at all.

Comment: you are right I did not call it. And did not really know that IIFE calls itself immediately. I will read more about it thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your example, you have a "global" variable `b` and a local variable `a`. Only `b` is visible outside of the function.

When you try to refer to `a` in your console output, it will refer to a "global" variable `a` (which is not yet defined).

`b` is "global" because there is no `var` statement that defines it. The `var` on that line only applies to `a`.

`a` is a local variable only visible inside of the function (nicely declared with `var`). However, you can still have variables in other parts of your program that are also called `a`. Your console output is an example for this. But these are completely separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `a` is inside a IIFE, so it won't be visible in a parent scope (it has `var` keyword behind it).

Variable `b` is presumed to be from outer scope of the IIFE (it does *not* have `var` keyword).

The way `typeof` operator works, it lets you put any valid variable name for a type test, even *undeclared* i.e.:

```
var a = 5;
var b;
console.log(typeof a); // number
console.log(typeof b); // undefined
console.log(typeof totallyNotMentionedAnywhereElse); // undefined
```